# AJAX returns data only after first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this ajax request script:

```
    function SendData(){
$( "#Submit" ).click(function() {
     $('#Submit').attr("disabled", true);
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"assets/process.php",
        data: {
            Years : $('#Years').val()
        },
        success: function(Response){
            if (Response.Status == 'Error') {                
                swal("Ups!", "Nemo' zebavaš", "error");
            } else if (Response.Status == 'Error0') {
                  swal("Ups!", "Servis 'Misterije' mogu koristiti samo rođene osobe!", "error");
            }
            else if (Response.Status == 'Error120') {
                  swal("Ups!", "Žao nam je! Niste podobni za korišćenje WEB Servisa 'Misterije'!", "error");
            } 
            else if (Response.Status == 'Success') {
                   swal("USPEŠNO!", 'Rođeni ste: '+Response.Calculated+' godine!', "success");
            }
            $('#Submit').attr("disabled", false);
        }
    });
});
}
```

When I load page in browser, add data to input and click on button nothing happens, but on second and all clicks after until I refresh page all working OK.
How I can slove this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call the function

Put your code in $(document).ready function

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you're *calling* this `SendData()` function when you click the button?

This function isn't doing what you think it's doing.  It's not invoking the AJAX request.  *All* this function does is *attach the click handler* to the button.  Nothing more.  Then the *next* time you click the button, that handler will execute.

(Not to mention that it would also again attach another click handler.  So the third click would invoke the handler twice.  And so on...)

There's no need to wrap all of this in a function.  Instead of this:

```
function SendData(){
  $( "#Submit" ).click(function() {
    // your code
  });
}
```

just do this:

```
$( "#Submit" ).click(function() {
  // your code
});
```

This will attach the click handler, not invoke it.  Any time afterward when you click the button the handler will be invoked.

At worst, you'd have to do this if the button doesn't exist yet when this code executes:

```
$(function () {
  $( "#Submit" ).click(function() {
    // your code
  });
});
```

This would wait until the `document.ready` event and *then* attach the handler.

(Note: You'll also want to remove any reference to `SendData()` once you've removed that function.  I'm assuming you're calling it in-line from the button.  But you don't need to do that when you're attaching a click handler with jQuery.)

Comment: I'm changed code and removed "$(function () {" and now on click on button with ID ''Submit" nothing happens.

Comment: @MiljanIlic: Are there any errors in your JavaScript console?  When you debug the code, what happens?  Does this code find the target element when it runs?  Is the click handler executed at all?  Where does it fail?  "nothing happens" isn't very descriptive of the problem, I'm afraid.  You need to do some debugging.

Comment: There no errors or warnings in console and debugger on Firefox

Comment: @MiljanIlic: And what happens when you step through the code in the debugger?  I can't debug this on your computer for you.

Comment: When I clicked on button I get this in console: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list index.php:44:4 On line 44 is script closing tag </script>

Comment: @MiljanIlic: Well, that doesn't exactly agree with your earlier statement that "there are no errors".  You have a syntax error somewhere, presumably on whatever line 44 is or just before it.

Comment: @MiljanIlic: That's exactly what `$(function() { /.../ });` does.  So I'm hesitant to believe that you've solved the problem, so much as changed it to a different and somewhat less obvious problem.  But if it works for you, that's good.